# MVC 3 Changing Model in Views with RenderPage

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model, ienumerable, renderpartial

I'm having problems when trying to change the model of my view in MVC 3.

First view (**index.cshtml**) :

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProgram.MyFrogCollection>

<h1>Welcome to my frog collection</h1>
@foreach(MyProgram.Frog frog in Model)
{
  <div class="frogDetails">
    @RenderPage("ShowFrogDetails.cshtml", frog);
  </div>
}
```

Second view (**ShowFrogDetails.cshtml**), that I would like to use all over the site :

```
@model MyProgram.Frog

<h3>Name:</h3><div class="detail">@Model.Name</div>
<h3>Colour:</h3><div class="detail">@Model.Colour</div>
```

However when I try to run the page **index.cshtml** after passing in a list of frog objects I get the following error when getting to the @RenderPage line :

> Server Error in '/' Application. The model item passed into the
>   dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyProgram.Frog]', but this
>   dictionary requires a model item of type 'MyProgram.Frog'.

If I were to remove the code from **ShowFrogDetails.cshtml** and place it in-line within the foreach loop of **index.cshtml** the results are what I would expect. However this doesn't reuse existing code.

Is there anyway I can change the model to a single Frog object for use in the RenderPage ?

Cheers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<div class="frogDetails">
    @Html.Partial("ShowFrogDetails", frog)
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, that does the job perfectly ! Cheers !